# toDataURL returns error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined "

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and am having an error. I'm sure I am skipping some basic concept... sorry.

here is the problem.

I use on my html this code:

```
<div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
document.write('<img src="'+myCanvas[0].toDataURL("image/png")+'"/>');

</script></div>
```

I have only one canvas on my document. The error I see in chrome is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined sankey.html:128 (anonymous function)
```

If I enter

```
document.write('<img src="'+myCanvas[0].toDataURL("image/png")+'"/>');
```

(the exact same line) in the java script chrome console, it works! How is this possible?

Comment: Without seeing more code one possible reason could be that your javascript is placed before your canvas element in your html file. This would cause your script to run before your canvas element exists. Afterwards when you use the console, it does exist and your code would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `[0]`:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns a array of elements, you'll have to select one out of it. (Even if the array only contains 1 element)

A "cleaner" way to do this would be to set a id (`id="myCanvas"`) on the canvas, and use `getElementById`, but since you're only using 1 canvas, `getElementsByTagName` will work.

The reason it was returning `undefined` is probably that your code was executed before the canvas was loaded.
Wrap your code in a function, then register the function to the "load" event

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var myCanvas;

    function initCanvas(){
        myCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
        document.write('<img src="'+myCanvas[0].toDataURL("image/png")+'"/>');
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', initCanvas, false);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm using myCanvas[0] to acces the first element in the line below... isn't this the same?

Comment: It is, yes, but if you want to assign the canvas element to a variable, it's usually more convenient to get the actual element, not a array containing that element. Hence the `[0]` after the `getElement`, instead of after `myCanvas `

Comment: I just tried your idea and it returns the same error on the same place :-( any other ideas?

Comment: the thing is: why does it work on the chrome console, and it does not work on the html code directly?

Comment: You'll need to execute your code after the document finishes loading.
Editing my answer...

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem! still magic for me, but it worked :-)